# Reading and interpreting JVM memory from C

Tags: java, c, jvm, reverse-engineering

So I'm trying to read the memory of a Java process from C code. I found documentation on the JVM structure (heap, perm gen, method area etc.) but none of these articles actually show how to find where these areas are in memory.

From what I understood, classes are stored in the method area and all instances in the heap on the first 32 bits have a pointer (I'm talking about x86 JVM) to these classes. I've tried the jmap and jhat utilities provided in the JDK hoping that I could find a "pattern" for the memory locations, but failed to do as they only show the memory location of the instances. The `ClassLoader` doesn't provide any pointers to classes and static fields but I found some memory locations for `Class` objects by applying reflection in the java program and looking at the referenced `Class` object memory location. There must be some way to determine where these things are stored otherwise the Java process wouldn't know how to fetch them either.

Can anyone provide some insight on how to find instances, classes, static fields in memory or point me in the right direction?

I know it's possible through Java code but I need this in C. Usage of JNI or modifying the Java program is not acceptable either as I need it entirely written in native code.

Comment: While the general approach to memory layout, memory management and garbage collection has been described in public talks, I don't think the details have ever been published. They are private implementation details. And some details certainly change with the JRE version, even minor ones.

Comment: Do you want to read memory of a foreign process, or a memory of JVM launched from within the same process?

Comment: @apangin From a foreign process which can launch the Java process if that benefits the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HotSpot Serviceability Agent](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bsa) can do this. It knows how to reconstruct JVM structures from memory of a foreign Java process or from a core dump.

Serviceability Agent has [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/serviceabilityagent/index.html) available at `{JDK}/lib/sa-jdi.jar`. It is feasible to implement similar functionality in C, though it would require much efforts.
Anyway, you may look at SA sources [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/312e113bc3ed/agent).

Comment: I went through the API docs and it looks like a good place to start. However I cannot get this to work on my windows 10 laptop. I switched to the 32 bit JRE when running the program in Eclipse and tried to attach to a simple Java process but it doesn't seem to work: http://i.imgur.com/YfYyvHc.png and the sawindbg.dll file is not even included in the JRE by default, I had to download it manually. Is there anything I can do about this or should I switch to an older JRE/JDK version (current using latest) ?

Comment: @MB Serviceability Agent is included in JDK, not in JRE. Here are SA usage examples: https://github.com/odnoklassniki/jvm-serviceability-examples/tree/master/src/demo3

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works great on linux. Is there any way this can work on windows too provided that it requires sawindbg.dll?

Comment: @MB SA works fine on Windows. However, in order to use it, you need JDK (not JRE) of exactly the same version that the target application is running on. For example, if the application runs on JRE 8u101 32-bit, you have to run SA on JDK 8u101 32-bit.

Comment: Alright, finally made it work on windows. I was talking about the JRE because it requires sawindbg.dll to be in the java.library.path which is generally set to jre/bin. I first downloaded it from the internet because I couldn't find it included in the jdk or jre which and it didn't work, but after searching through my pc I found it in the database folders at $ORACLE_HOME/jdk/jre/bin and this one works. Thanks for the help, it's exacly what I needed. I'll just go from here and try to replicate some more native solutions.